# Como eliminar variaveis que tenham alguns valores NA no R

Tags: r

Atualmente eu tenho um data frame com variáveis textuais e numéricas. Porém, algumas variáveis tem `NA` em apenas algumas observações, não todas. Por exemplo, tenho o data frame a seguir

```
Cidade      Estado populacao idh   area
Salvador    BA     21212     3     NA   
Salvador    BA     21212     NA    23323 
Salvador    BA     21212     3     23323
Salvador    BA     21212     3     23323
Salvador    BA     21212     NA    23323
```

No caso eu precisava eliminar de vez a variáveis `IDH` e `AREA`. Só que no meu exemplo eu tenho mais de 2 mil variáveis, de modo que não dá para analisar uma por uma. Como resolver isso? Note que desejo excluir a variável (coluna), não a observação (linha).

Comment: Só para ficar claro: o objetivo é eliminar toda e qualquer coluna que tenha pelo menos uma observação igual a `NA`?

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira em R base é a seguinte. A cada coluna da base aplicar (`sapply`) a função `anyNA`.

```
dados[, !sapply(dados, anyNA)]
#    Cidade Estado populacao
#1 Salvador     BA     21212
#2 Salvador     BA     21212
#3 Salvador     BA     21212
#4 Salvador     BA     21212
#5 Salvador     BA     21212
```

Teste de ambas as soluções, esta e a do usuário [neves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447712/82237), com o pacote `microbenchmark`.

Mas com uma tabela com cerca de 2000 colunas. Como a tabela exemplo da pergunta tem 5 colunas, bastam

```
log2(2000/5)
#[1] 8.643856
```

nove iterações de `cbind()` para ter mais de 2000 colunas. Vou aproveitar para também ter mais linhas.

```
d2 <- dados
for(i in 1:10) d2 <- rbind(d2, d2)
for(i in 1:9) d2 <- cbind(d2, d2)
dim(d2)
#[1] 5120 2560

mb <- microbenchmark(
  colSums = d2[, colSums(is.na(d2)) == 0],
  anyNA = d2[, !sapply(d2, anyNA)]
)
print(mb, unit = "relative", order = "median")
#Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   anyNA 1.000000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000 1.000000   100  a 
# colSums 3.429795 11.07481 10.40991 10.90102 10.81671 6.761014   100   b


ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Considere o conjunto de dados a seguir:

```
dados <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), y = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 2, NA), 
               w = c(88, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8), z = c(5, 2, 2, 9, NA, 18))
```

Para eliminar as varíaveis que contenham `NA`s você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
dados[, colSums(is.na(dados)) == 0]
```